# Error al insertar un archivo csv a postgresql

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

espero se encuentren bien.Estoy tratando de copiar un archivo csv que traje de sql server a postgresql, pero cuando intento copiar, cuando no me da el error de que el código de empleado es un string, ahora me da el error **extra data after last expected column**, pero no se ha añadido ninguna columna, además de que la tabla en postgres tiene la misma estructura que la tabla de sql. Por favor, si alguien tiene la solución se lo agradezco muchísimo, esto me tiene muy estrezado.

La sentencia que estoy utilizando es la siguiente:

`COPY tbl_empleado_prueba FROM 'C:\DBtblEmpleados\tbl_empleado_prueba.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV ENCODING 'UTF8';`

Comment: Deberias completar tu pregunta con la estructura de la tabla y un ejemplo de que trae el archivo `.csv`. Sin eso no podremos ayudarte

Comment: El error indica que hay más datos en la fila que columnas en el csv. Revisa si pusiste un dato extra en el csv. Solo por adivinar, si uno de los datos tiene una coma y dicho dato no esta entre comillas, el parser va a creer que se trata de dos datos.

Comment: Es probable que un caracter especial esté causando problemas. Puede ser también que el archivo se haya corrompido en algún momento.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos los que comentaron, Marc que me disculpe porque no podía publicar el csv (la primera persona que comentó) lo que sucede es que el archivo es confidencial y hay datos sensibles, pero gracias a todos los que comentaron. Tenía el siguiente problema.

Estaba realizando una consulta en sql server, guardaba el query en formato csv, cuando lo guardaba de esa manera lo que hacía era que algunas columnas como que se ligaban con otras, para solucionar esto lo que hice fue que realicé el query nuevamente y copié todo a un archivo excel y ahí todas las columnas ya estaban donde tenían que estar y por ende los registros, luego pude copiarlo en postgres. Espero que esto pueda ayudar a otra persona que tal vez pase por esto.

Comment: Para eso entonces uno hace un ejemplo con datos falsos y así nadie tiene que adivinar. Para obtener buenas respuestas hay que echarle un poquito de ganas a la pregunta

Comment: Disculpa @Alfabravo tienes toda la razón y disculpa los inconvenientes, para la próxima lo tendré muy en cuenta. Gracias a todos.